# Any event for each printed page?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

In WPF, using `PrintDialog` and `FixedDocument`, is there an event (or any other way) of getting notified as each page prints?

### Detail

My Fargo printer includes a Magstripe encoder, so it can encode magnetic data onto cards in addition to standard raster printing. For magnetic encoding, I need to use Fargo SDK and call some functions with specifically formatted track data to be encoded.

Let's say I have a `FixedDocument` containing raster data for 20 cards. I send this document to WPF's printing engine using `PrintDialog.PrintDocument()`. Here is the problem. I need to call magnetic encoding functions after each card is printed, but apparently there is no way of getting a notification (something like a `PrintPage` event) that I could intercept and call SDK functions therein.

This is unlike WinForms printing engine where `PrintPage` event is fired and we compose our output within that event using GDI+.

Is there a way to get notified after each page of a `FixedDocument` is printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out myself. It looks like the magstripe printers (or at least the Fargo printer I have) treat `TextBlock` elements that have magstripe-formatted data in the `Text` property as a special case. Instead of sending them as normal raster output, they are sent to the magnetic encoder for writing them to the magnetic tape. So for example, if your `TextBlock` looks like any of the following:

```
<TextBlock Text="~1%DATA?" />
<TextBlock Text="~2;DATA?" />   
<TextBlock Text="~3;DATA?" />
```

this will be sent to the magstripe encoder instead of the raster printer. Note the specific characters that need to be prepended and append for each track (Track 1, 2 and 3 respectively). In addition, there are specific list of characters that is allowed for each track. More details can be found on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card).

So this allows WPF developers to use standard WPF practices (and even MVVM) to print magstripe cards using `PrintDialog` and `FixedDocument` classes without requiring a `PrintPage` event.